# Gps On App only works after Using Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

We have this android app that uses the maps api. Now when we run it, it usually doesn't work, when we call

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
100, 0, this, null);
```

It doesn't really work, the LocationListener's onLocationChanged method is never called. However, if we run Google Maps and wait until the gps icon is on in the status bar, then our app does start calling onLocationChanged. So my question is, how is Google Maps "activating" gps, or if they're not activating it, what are they doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn on GPS first:

```
try {
  Settings.Secure.setLocationProviderEnabled(getContentResolver(), LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, true);
} catch (Exception e) {
  logger.log(Log.ERROR, e, e.getMessage());
}
```

To do that, you also need to have permission from end-user i believe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-
we have to register location listener with the locationManager.onLocationChanged method will  be execute, when we provide locationlitener

```
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
 100, 0, this, locationlistener);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with removing :
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>` from AndroidManifest.xml
and i just kept `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`