# GPS Cold start delay while using HTML5 geolocation

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, gps

We have a HTML5 based web application which needs a GPS position at irregular interval (up to days). The application gets a position quickly when used on land, where there are fixed wifi hotspots or, depending on the platform used, cell towers.

However offshore (where the application is often used), the only data connection is via a Mobile WIFI hotspot. It suffers from an unacceptable delay getting any position at all, presumably because it is acquiring the GPS almanac via the GPS satellite, rather than through the data connection.

In the same environment, dedicated Apps such as Google Maps come up with a position with only a brief delay. And in fact, running our Web page subsequent to activating the Google Maps App, it works fine!

This is similar to another question here, "[Gps On App only works after Using Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646477/gps-on-app-only-works-after-using-google-maps)", but the solution suggested there is only available as an App, not HTML5

Any suggestions?